# how to get updated changes of github files reflected in google colab?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I made changes in my python file on github. While running code on Google Colab, those changes are not reflected in goolge colab and it gives me the same previous error. Can anyone share solution to this?

Comment: Did you run `git pull`? What is the previous error you mention?

Comment: Yes, I ran git pull. Previous error means error I got before making changes. After making changes on github, I am supposed to get new error or some result. But that is not happening. I have to open a new colab everytime to see the changes. How to resolve this?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to solve this too, and at some point colab was updated with the latest commit. So I guess the update must be hapenning automatically once in every few minutes.